# I’ve always heard about the dreaded ramp check. What does it actually entail?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa

What happens during a ramp check? How likely are you to experience one? What happens if they find something wrong? (A major and a minor example if you don’t mind)

Comment: Related: [What information am I legally required to provide during a FAA ramp check?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/634/14897)